# How do you insert a lxml tag with namespace while skipping xmlns?

Tags: python, lxml, python-docx

I'm trying to write my python scripts using python-docx to add equations to docx files. Since this is not supported by python-docx yet, I need to modify the OOXML directly using lxml. I'd need to add some tags so the resulting XML looks like this:

```
<m:r>
    <m:t>(5−x)</m:t>
</m:r>
```

I can't create a new naked
`<m:r>`
node using lxml. Using something like the following code

```
new_node = etree.Element('{m}r', nsmap={'m': ''})
```

gives me a
`<m:r xmlns:m="m">`
node, except I don't need the xmlns part. (python-docx handles the remaining XML operations for me, and if the xmlns is there, the docx file actually wouldn't be recognised by MS Word.) Is there any way to make a naked
`<m:r>`
node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-docx` is aware of the `"m": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"` namespace-prefix mapping: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/ns.py#L18

So you can use `python-docx` internals to create such an element:

```
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement

r = OxmlElement("m:r")
```

You can then use that element like you would any other `lxml` element, like appending or inserting it as a child of some other element.